# How to get if a code exist in parse.com?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a problem, I have this structure in parse.com in "VerificationCode" db:

[image]

When someone inserts a code in my app, it automatically adds in the "attachedUser" column the id of the user who is stored locally and I call it "ParseInstallObject.codigo2" and I get the id of the user for example to see it in a textview, etc.

The problem is that I want to check if the user id exists in parse or not; and if it exists do something or if not exist do another thing.

I used a code that I see in the documentation of parse.com but it always shows that the code exists. This is my code:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("VerificationCode");
    query2.whereEqualTo("attachedUser", ParseInstallObject.codigo2);
    query2.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                comprobar.setText("exist");
                comprobar2.setText("exist");

            } else {
                comprobar.setText("no exist");
                comprobar2.setText("no exist");

            }
        }
    });
```

How can I see if the user has a valid code or not?

Comment: What was the output of Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores") ?? If its >0 ,it means the user exists. Print the scoreList and see what it points to. Probably, the ParseInstallObject is causing an issue. Try the query with "code" instead of "attachedUser" to verify this.

Comment: Sorry i missed to delete the log.d("scro... .I tried with code, and y also give the answer "exists". But the problem is that if i put "cosigo2" instead of "ParseInstallObject.codigo2" codigo2 is null

Comment: e==null means that the call was successfully completed by the server.

Comment: And what i need to put if i want to check if thw code exists?

Comment: Please check my reply below and also add the previous Log statement(scoreList size) and provide the result.

Comment: change "attachedUser" to "code" to check if the code exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
e==null means that the call was successfully completed by the server. It does not imply that the user exists or not.
if(e==null){
if(scoreList == null || scoreList.isEmpty()){
 // The user does not exist.
}else{
// the user exists.
}
}else {
// You have an exception (like HTTPTimeout, etc). Handle it as per requirement.
}
```